# Empty functions are equal in Agda (without functional extensionality)

Tags: agda

Can I prove that two empty functions (functions from the empty domain) are equal?

More concretely, is it possible to prove in Agda the following: `eqf : ∀ {A : Set} (f g : ⊥ → A) → f ≡ g`

Edit: as @Sassa-NF points out in the comments, if extensionality is present, then this can be proven. I am interested in whether this can be proven *without* extensionality.

Comment: If you have extensionality of functions axiom, then equality of empty functions is provable in simple ways.

Comment: I would like to know if it is possible to prove it without any extra axiom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible to prove in plain Martin-Löf Type Theory (and hence should also be unprovable in Agda without extra assumptions). The paper "The Next 700 Syntactic Models of Type Theory" (https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01445835/file/main.pdf) describes a general technique to construct models of type theory that refute claims like this.