# Intuition for difference between eta for function from top and empty functions in Agda

Tags: agda, type-theory

In Agda, it seems it is not possible to show `∀ {A : Set} (f : ⊥ → A) → f ≡ λ ()`.

However, the seemingly similar term  `∀ {A : Set} (f : ⊤ → A) → f ≡ λ _ → f tt`  can be proven by `refl`. It can be later used to prove a form of extensionality for `⊤`:

`ext⊤ : ∀ {A : Set} (f g : ⊤ → A) (H : ∀ x → f x ≡ g x) → f ≡ g`

According to [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60849180/13122298), the explanation might be in considering different models of type theory. Is it possible to have any intuition on why one is accepted and not the other? Shouldn't `f ≡ λ ()` be some form of eta law?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `⊤` type has the eta rule which says that any terms with that type are definitionally equal. Hence, `f ≡ (λ x → f x) ≡ (λ x → f tt)`.

`⊥` does not have an eta rule in Agda. If `f : ⊥ → A`, then we only know that `f ≡ λ x → f x`. `λ ()` is essentially syntactic sugar for `⊥-elim`, and `f` is not definitionally equal to `⊥-elim`.

Comment: Is there a reason why there is no eta rule in Agda for the empty type?

Comment: The full eta rule for `⊥` has undecidable type checking, it says something like "everything is equal to everything if `⊥` can be proved from the scope". We could decidably have something weaker than full eta, which says all terms with `⊥` type are equal, but I guess people haven't really felt the need for that.

Comment: In this last option, i.e. weaker eta that says that all terms with type `⊥` are equal, then it could be possible to prove that `λ x → f x ≡ ⊥-elim`? It doesn't seem so, right?

Comment: It would not be possible to prove that. `⊥-elim` has type `⊥ → A` which is not `⊥`.

Comment: Note that you can define a new empty type as a record type with a single irrelevant field of type `⊥` which does satisfy (the weak form of) eta equality that all its terms are equal. Equivalently, on Agda 2.6.0 and up you can use `--prop` to define `⊥` as a datatype in `Prop` instead of in `Set`, which satisfies the same laws.

Answer (score 2):

I draw your attention that the first statement is attempting to prove the uniqueness of `⊥ → A`. Usually it is true up to isomorphism.

The full correspondence would have been between `∀ {A : Set} (f : ⊤ → A) → f ≡ λ _ → f tt` and `∀ {A : Set} (f : ⊥ → A) → f ≡ λ _ → f ()` - the expression for `⊤` constructs the value `tt`, so you should be constructing a value for `⊥`.

Agda has no means of constructing a value of `⊥`, so `()` is not a valid constructor, it is only a placeholder for what you want.

Although it isn't really pattern-matching, it probably is not harmful to see the use of `()` as pattern-matching for the empty type - it is allowed to occur only in the pattern-matching positions.

This is intended to show the similarity is superficial, so should amend your intuition about the expressions.

> Shouldn't `f ≡ λ ()` be some form of eta law?

It is not clear what you would gain from that. Many things can be proven only up to isomorphism. So, for example, proving the uniqueness of `⊥ → A` could correspond to proving the uniqueness of `A → ⊤` (not eta-equality of `f` and `λ _ → f tt`). Both of these is doable.